# Is vuejs component's style global to other components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have two pages:

1. `search.php` that contains a vuejs component called `search.vue`
2. `person.php` that contains another component called `person.vue`.

In `search.vue`, I have links to `person.php`.

How come the styles set in the component `search.vue` also affect the DOM in `person.vue`?

The `style` tag in my `search.vue` component:

```
<style>
  .row {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
```

There is nowhere I connect these two views except through the `href` link to open the `person.php` page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Styles defined in the `style` tag of a Vue single-file-component will be compiled to a singular file, affecting all components.

But, you can specify a `scoped` attribute on the component's `style` tag:

```
<style scoped>
  .row {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
```

From the [Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/comparison.html#Component-Scoped-CSS):

> The optional `scoped` attribute automatically scopes this CSS to your component by adding a unique attribute (such as `data-v-21e5b78`) to elements and compiling `.list-container:hover` to something like `.list-container[data-v-21e5b78]:hover`.

---

Note that the `scoped` attribute is a Vue feature for single-file-components, different from the general [`scoped` style tag attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style#attr-scoped), which has a similar effect but is currently only supported by Firefox.

Comment: However, note that `scoped` is only supported by Firefox, and has been removed from the CSS specification.
http://caniuse.com/#search=scoped

Comment: @Roy J: this scope has nothing to do with the css scope style. This scope is translated ( transpiled?) to a normal css it just add a unique attribute to the elements and creates the corresponding css selector . So it is completely legal to use

Comment: @RoyJ Thanks for bringing up a potential source of confusion though. I hadn't heard of the more general `scoped` attribute for style tags.